# wpf calling particular array item from button

Tags: wpf-controls, binding, observablecollection, itemscontrol

I have a `Movie` class with a `Dim _characters = New ObservableCollection(of String)`

In my **MainWindow.vb** i have,

`Dim movies = New ObservableCollection(of Movie)`
`Me.parentG.DataContext = Me.movies`

i want to add characters to the movie based on button click at runtime.
How can i get the particaular movie for which the character button was clicked?

**MainWindow.xaml:-**

```
  <Grid Name="parentG" >

   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>

       <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>      
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="700"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding MovieName}" />
       <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="New Character" Click="newCharacterButton_Click" Height="20" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

       <ListBox Grid.Column="2" Name="cList" ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}">  
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
             <DataTemplate >
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>  
             </DataTemplate> 
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>  
         </ListBox> 

        </Grid>

      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>

 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out. Below are the steps  :-

1. in the button handler, convert sender to `Button`
2. get its parent, in my case it was the `Grid`
3. Get the `DataContext` of the Grid, convert it to (in this case), `Movie`
4. Get index of this `Movie` in the `Movie array`, assuming an index property existed for each `Movie`, and was set during initialization.
5. Add a `character` to this `movie`